# rowSpan hides rows

Tags: html-table, xhtml

```
<table>
   <tr>   <td rowspan="2">1</td>  <td>2</td>   </tr>
   <tr>   <td rowspan="2">3</td>               </tr>
   <tr>   <td>4</td>                           </tr>
</table>
```

seemingly only displays two rows:

[image]

The reason for hiding the second row [1 3] is, that the cells with text 1 and 3 are reduced in height. Is there a way to ensure, that the second row is visible in the display (not only in DOM)?

The problem gets clearer, if you look at the same table with an additional column:

```
<table>
   <tr>   <td rowspan="2">1</td>  <td>2</td> <td>0</td> </tr>
   <tr>   <td rowspan="2">3</td>             <td>0</td> </tr>
   <tr>   <td>4</td>                         <td>0</td> </tr>
</table>
```

which is displayed like:

[image]

Comment: Is adding `height` to the cells an option? `td[rowspan] {height:2.5em}` goes a long way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a height property to the row:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 1.5em">
    <td rowspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. However, in order to have the correct height, compared to a table without rowSpan, we should use 1em. Additionally, the solution implies, that you know the row, that has to have the height, so a general solution is, to add the style "height:1em" to each row. In my case, the table is generated, so no algorithm has to compute anything. You might edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: May be the easiest solution is to add CSS for your table like: #myTable tr { height:1em }

Answer (score 0):

One suboptimal option could be to add an empty column:

```
<table>
   <tr> <td rowspan="2">1</td> <td>2</td>             <td class="void"></td> </tr>
   <tr>                        <td rowspan="2">3</td> <td class="void"></td> </tr>
   <tr> <td>4</td>                                    <td class="void"></td> </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table,td {border:1px solid}
.void {height:1em;padding:0;border:0}
```

However, the spacing between columns leads to unnecessary space for the added column:

[image: Artificial empty column]

As this problem could be solved with padding-left for TD and a cellspacing of 0 for the table, this solution would not be general enough, so I'm still waiting for a good idea.